# License: "Just Dance" hardly usable without a subscription? And do I really have to buy a new release every year (2019, 2024 etc)?

Tags: nintendo-switch, ubisoft-connect, just-dance-3

My child loves ["Just Dance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_Dance_(video_game_series)), but says that a lot of things don't work with our old Nintendo Switch release.

> Just Dance is a rhythm game series developed and published by Ubisoft.
> The original Just Dance game was released on the Wii in 2009 in North
> America, Europe, and Australia.

Somehow you have to buy a subscription, which I don't want, I'd rather pay once and not register everywhere (Privacy issues).

I have seen that there is an upgrade every year with an annual number. Do I have to upgrade every year or what is the advantage of having the latest version?

Why exactly do I need a subscription? There is very aggressive advertising for the subscription. What is the advantage of the subscription?

What can my child do without a subscription and a few years old "Just Dance" release?

Comment: Apparently Ubisoft (being Ubisoft) made additional songs available via a paid subscription instead of buy once DLC. The service seems to have many trash features attached: first, it is not valid for every version - Just Dance 2022 and before use a sub called "Just Dance Unlimited" while Just Dance 2023/2024 have "Just Dance Plus" - if you want to upgrade you can't (any month left is lost). Second, it is a sub, you can only play the additional songs as long as the sub is active. Third, seems to have auto-renew.

Comment: Fourth, no cross-play, so if you by chance have both the Switch and the PS version of the game you have to buy TWO subs.
Seems pretty lame if you have to ask. I would have suggested moving to something more ethical like Project Diva Future Tone (220+ songs with all the buy once DLC) or even OSU! on pc... but those are "pure" button-pressing rhythm games while Just Dance has you... well, dancing.

Comment: relevant and timely article: [Ubisoft Exec Says Gamers Need To Get Comfortable With "Not Owning Your Games"](https://www.thegamer.com/ubisoft-plus-subscription-exec-gamers-need-to-get-comfortable-with-not-owning-your-games/). This games-player says that Ubisoft executives need to get comfortable with me "Not buying your games"

Comment: @Sybil https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubisoft_games:_2020%E2%80%93present, tl;dr: Assassin's Creed, Far Cry, Just Dance, Prince of Persia, Tom Clancy's franchise, Watch Dogs, The Crew, TrackMania, Trials and Rayman.

Comment: @AaronF: Well that's obviously clownshoes. The 2023 GOTY (Baldur's Gate 3) isn't on any subscription service and Larian has said that it never will be. Nobody is moving to an all-subscription model if they can't even play the most recent GOTY that way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Each Just Dance game has a set list of songs that come included with that version, and typically also includes new game modes. Unfortunately, some of these game modes tend to be restricted to Ubisoft's subscription membership, or utilize songs that are part of that membership.

For example, Just Dance 2024's song list was recently announced, along with a new challenge mode: [Just Dance 2024 Edition Song List and New Mode Details](https://news.ubisoft.com/en-us/article/4XASVBQVlNLtGtyO6fj1DQ/just-dance-2024-edition-song-list-and-new-mode-details)

Unless there is a specific single player mode you want to play, or want to have some new/more recently popular songs, that are included with the *base game* there isn't any real reason to buy new iterations of the game. The games previously purchased will continue to work in single player mode with the songs that come "included" with the game. Do note, though, that you are correct that these games do aggressively promote "bonus" content tied to the Ubisoft subscription. Many of the games even place these subscription-only songs in the same song selection sections as the ones that came with the game, which can give the appearance as if some songs of the games are not working or inaccessible without subscription. As long as you stick with the songs that came with the game, you should be able to play these past games without issue. The list of songs that come on each game can be found on the [Just Dance wiki](https://justdance.fandom.com/wiki/Just_Dance_(series)) by clicking the respective game and going to the Track List section.